# Fourier Transform of Fractional Laplacian

Tags: fourier-series, spectral-theory, fractional-calculus

I'm trying to solve a PDE with a spectral method.

The PDE has a fractional Laplacian... $\Delta^s$.

In regards to a numerical implementation, will the "s" term simply become the exponent of the "differentiation matrices".

$\widehat{(-\Delta)^s f}(\xi) = |\xi|^{2s} \hat f(\xi).$

Or is it not so simple?

Comment: It is that simple if the domain is $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Or p-adic field $ \mathbb Q_p$. Should be so on any self-dual locally compact topological group that has some kind of algebraical norm.

Answer (score 0):

The equation there is just the standard definition of fractional Laplacian in terms of the Fourier transform. See for instance the surverys

https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4345

https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.03347

The subject of numerical methods for equations involving the fractional Laplacian is of course very broad and an area of active research. See for instance the paper

https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.03347

for an approach based on the finite element method.